# System Hangs between installing Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation

I've recently upgraded my laptop from Intel Dual-Core to Intel Core2Duo. When I tried running the already installed Windows 7 Ultimate after upgrade, it started hanging after few minutes. Guessing some compatibility issue, I tried reinstalling it, but it always stopped on Expanding new files at 27%.
I've tried reformatting my harddisk, deleting partitions, even tried pirated versions, though I had original DVD with me. It still hangs at different places. I am using Windows XP on it currently, which is working fine, but I need Win 7 on it.
I've tried installing Windows 7 on another laptop with the same old configuration I had on this laptop before upgrade, and it worked, even the pirated ones too.
What could be wrong here??

Comment: PS: I am using Windows 7 Ultimate x86, tried x64 too.

Answer (score 0):

How long did you wait at the 27% freeze?

*% hangs are usually a Ram issue, [test your ram](http://www.memtest.org/)

sometimes just re-seating the ram modules cures it also.

Comment: I've waited for whole night ;) Trying the link.

Comment: I've tested the ram, using MemTest86+ for 10 passes, and there was no errors.

Comment: Let the ram test run overnight to stress test the ram.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swapping in the origional CPU?

There are a lot of variables that are chagned in testing install media on a different machine.

I would suggest a good long format of the drive. Alternativly, do you know a friend that has a copy of [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm)? Spinrite has fixed issues like this before.

Comment: I don't have the original CPU :(