# How to get audio output

Tags: windows-xp, audio, motherboard

I upgraded my laptop's processor and motherboard, but didn't check completely if it's working or not, because I was using another laptop. Now when I checked it, there was no audio output from it. I've formatted it many times and installed audio drivers, updated those drivers, but it's not working.
I can't go back to the service center as it was in warranty when they upgraded it, but now it's out of warranty.
So is there any way to get back the audio without changing the motherboard or is there any way i can check if I need to change the motherboard or not.

PS: The sound is not coming from inbuilt speakers and headphones both.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the connection on the motherboard going to the speakers is attached?

Does the system devices panel suggest there is a problem with sound (exclamation mark: !) or does it suggest it is working correctly?

Comment: it suggests that it's working correctly, no exclamation mark is there.

Answer (score 0):

If it was just the speakers, then it could have been that the speaker connection had been missed when the laptop was re-assembled.  However, the headphone jack is soldered to the motherboard.  So... it's not a connection issue.

Do the audio devices show up as if they have been installed properly, in Device Manager?  Does a speaker icon show up next to the clock as if the computer thinks there is a sound device installed and working?

Which audio drivers are you attempting to install?  The ones that came with your computer originally, or the ones that are specific to the new replacement motherboard that you got?  Chances are, since your laptop was upgraded to include a new processor and motherboard, that the audio device is not the same kind as what you used to have.

Did you install Windows fresh after the new hardware or did you use the same installation?  It is also entirely possible that Windows update replace your audio drivers with something similar (AC97 with CMedia, as has been seen in the past... CMedia is supposed to *be* AC97, but there isn't always compatibility).

Have you tested the laptop with another OS, like a LiveCD of Linux?  Download [Linux Mint](http://www.linuxmint.com/download.php), burn a dvd from the ISO, and boot to it.  If you hear sound once you are in the OS, then you know the problem is your install of Windows.

Comment: I've reinstalled the OS multiple times already, the device manager is showing that there's a device and it's working fine. All the icons are there. I've used the original disc to install drivers, but I updated them from the manufacturer's website too.

Comment: Another thing is I can't install any OS other than windows XP in it. There's a separate unanswered question for this problem too - http://superuser.com/questions/406065/system-hangs-between-installing-windows-7

Comment: I'm not saying anything about installing another OS.  I'm saying to boot to a DVD, and use a LiveOS.  You don't have to install anything.  Heck, you could pull the hard drive completely out of the computer before you boot to the DVD.

Comment: Oh, let me try that :D

Comment: The other issue could be that the new motherboard uses HD audio, which would require the additional installation of the Microsoft UAA pack for XP http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888111